# Inserting into joined tables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I just got a joined table set up and running in CodeIgniter; I am retrieving data from the DB very easily using ActiveRecord. The next obstacle though, seems like the hardest: I am new to joins and I have no idea how I'm going to insert data into my joined tables. The data should go in looking the same as it comes out (meaning actual data, not row ids) but short of hard-coding arrays of associations and transforming the data before save, I don't know how I'm going to do that. But there has to be a way, right?

Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't know CodeIgniter, but I can imagine how it should work based on other PHP ORMs.

```
$something = new ModelObject();
$something->setSomeProperty($someVal);
$something->save();

$related = new RelatedObject();
$related->setModelId($something->getId());
$related->save();
```

In other words, once you create the object represented by one table, that object's property corresponding to the generated identifier is populated for you. Now you can use it when you create an object in the related ("join") table to set the foreign key property before saving.